# Water looks like wax

Tags: fluid-simulation

I created a simple water simulation. I want to fill in a not visible glass with soda. But it looks like wax.
Resolution Division: 128 (I changed to 256, but it looks like the same).
[image]

My invidible cylinder has 256 vertice and the Dissusion is "water".

How can I get a clean and realistic surface on the side of my cylinder?
File added.

[image]

Comment: pls provide blend file because you didn't show us useful informations. It might be just your material you used. Or your render engine...or...did you use cycles?

Comment: @Chris file added :)

Comment: Have you modelled at the "real life" scale? It's really important for all simulations for you to 'Apply Scale' for any changes and make sure you're modelling at a realistic size (if using "Blender Units" then 1BU is equivalent to 1 metre).

Comment: @RichSedman yes, all objects are scaled. My glass has 2,3 x 2,3 x 4m in Blender

Comment: Will the glass stay hidden or will be visible in the final render? Try a lower value like 1 for *Mesh > Upres Factor* and *Mesh > Particle Radius*